# Nginx with 1 domain, 2 apps. Ror + nodejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, express, nginx, server

Hey.
After a few hours of research I couldn't find any easy how-to solutions for my problem.

I have written earlier a RoR app that's deployed on my server and running just fine. Now I'm trying to deploy also a Nodejs app to run alongside my RoR app. The two apps don't have anything to do with each other - they are to be used separately.

I only have one domain to use and I'm trying to use Nginx.
The RoR app is running on Unicorn + Nginx already.

My first question is what is the correct way to deploy two separate apps alongside on the same server?
Should they listen to different ports? Other to port :80 and other to :81 for example?
Or should I alternatively use sub folders? Going for exampleDomain/app1 and exampleDomain/app2?
I also read about an option of creating sub domains, but does this work when running my apps in production?

My RoR app is deployed following these instructions:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04
(as a note I'm using Digital Ocean's virtual server)

Currently my Nginx file looks the following:

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/deploy/appname/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/deploy/appname/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

It's a direct copy from the above RoR tutorial. For some reason if I switch the file name it stops working? Even that I couldn't find the file name being defined anywhere.
The file is under /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and named "default".

I tried to follow this tutorial for deploying the Nodejs app:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04
I get my app running with pm2. And I tried writing the following code in another file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and also including the code in the existing default file alongside with the code for RoR but neither of them worked.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Nginx logs are not showing anything useful either. I ran
 `sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` 
a couple of times but the logs were empty.

I would be really thankful if someone could give me some guidance which way to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question "How to put two apps on same server?".**

All those approaches you mentioned will work, but probably the cleanest way for you and potential users would be to use a subdomain. To do this,

1) Decide on your subdomain (ie. nodejs.example.com and ror.example.com) and point both of those to your server.

2) In your 2 ngnix files for each name set the server name to the respective subdomain:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ror.example.com;

  # Rest of conf below (pointing to ROR project)
}
```

And:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name nodejs.example.com

  # Rest of conf below (pointing to nodejs project)
}
```

**Second Question: "Where do I place these files?"**

To see where these files are actually used by nginx, I'd first look at the main nginx.conf file usually in the location: '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'. There should be 2 lines near the end that tell you where nginx is looking for conf files:

```
http {
  # A bunch of default nginx settings

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

If this is what is in your nginx.conf file, then nginx never will look in the sites-available folder. Where nginx is actually looking is in the two folders: /etc/nginx/conf.d/ and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled What I would suggest is do 3 things:

1) cd into /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder. Remove the 'default' file.

2) create 2 files, nodejs and ror, and put the resptive nginx configurations into both of those files within the folder: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

3) Run:

```
sudo service nginx reload
sudo service nginx restart
```

If reload fails, run the following to help debug the configuration:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

This will show the file and line number of the issue.

Hope this helps. Comment if you have trouble with any of this.

Comment: How is it possible to point `server_name nodejs.example.com` on `node app.js` like default cmd run?